# custom html inside errorElement of jquery Validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm putting my error message inside a `div` (errorElement) and giving it `errorClass:"callout border-callout error`, which I require to custom style it.
This is how it looks now:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail Address"/>
<div id="email-id" class="callout border-callout error"><!-- this is my error div -->
    Here is my error message
</div>
```

but I want two more elements inside this `errorElement` so i can style it properly. Ideally, it should look as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail Address"/>
<div id="email-id" class="callout border-callout error"><!-- this is my error div -->
    Here is my error message
    <b class="border-notch notch"></b>
    <b class="notch"></b>
</div>
```

My current jquery validate code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            fname: {
                required: true,
            },
            lname: {
                required: true,
            }

        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: 'Please enter your email',
                email: 'Please enter a valid email'
            },
            fname: {
                required: 'Please enter your First Name',
            },
            lname: {
                required: 'Please enter your Last Name',
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(jsonResponse) {
                                //Example json object returned by server: [false, "You have already subscribed!"]
                                var notyType;
                                if (jsonResponse.response) {
                                    notyType = 'success';
                                } else {
                                    notyType = 'error';
                                }
                                showNoty(jsonResponse.message, notyType);
                            }
                        });
        },
        errorClass: "error callout border-callout",


    });


});
```

## UPDATE:

```
<form method="post" id='form1' class="subscription-form">
   <div class="subscription-form-email">
       <span class="input-row"><input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your E-Mail Address"/></span>
       <div id="email-id" class="callout border-callout error" style="display:none"> 
            <b class="border-notch notch"></b>
            <b class="notch"></b>
       </div>
       <span class="input-row"><input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name"/></span>
       <span class="input-row"><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name"/></span>
   </div>

   <input type="submit" value="SUBSCRIBE" class="submit-button" name="submit" id="submitButton" title="Click here to submit your message!" />

</form>
```

Comment: Show enough HTML markup so that a working demo could be constructed.

Comment: You have invalid HTML. There are two opening `div` tags and three closing `/div` tags.  I also don't see any attempts at solving this yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, and shabby code, will fix the issues now

Comment: @Sparky , edited the code, last closing div was just a stray one left from deleting some unnecessary code there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple issues with your code that need to be corrected...

1)  Fix the HTML.  You have mismatched `div` tags... specifically, you have one more `</div>` than you have `<div>`.  I don't see any other HTML issues, but your layout looks like an unusual mix of `div` elements with `input` elements nested inside `span` elements.  If you want those `span` elements to behave like rows, then IMHO, they should be `div` elements instead.

2)  The error class, `border-callout`, is a real problem.  Although it may be technically ok to have `class` names that contain hyphens, it's bad practice.  Why?  Because JavaScript will interpret that hyphen as a minus sign.  [Your unedited code in a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6Gsg/) shows that the error messages will stack up on each other instead of toggling.  [Simply removing `border-callout` from `errorClass`, clears that issue right up](http://jsfiddle.net/U6Gsg/1/).

---

As far as what you're asking... how to insert the error message into a predefined `div` full of other HTML.

First, you're going to have to put the message into some kind of container of its own... `label`, `p`, `span`, etc.  It's how the plugin needs it so it can be targeted.  Unless you specify it with the `errorElement` option, the plugin will just use `label` by default.

```
<div id="email-id" class="callout border-callout error"><!-- this is my error div -->
    <label>Here is my error message</label><!-- message must be inside a container -->
    <b class="border-notch notch"></b>
    <b class="notch"></b>
</div>
```

Then place the message label object inside your `<div>` using the `errorPlacement` callback function and a bunch of jQuery DOM traversal methods...

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertBefore(element.parent().next('div').children().first());
}
```

Breakdown:

```
 error         // the error object (includes message and its label container)
.insertBefore( // insert the error object before what's defined inside ()
   element     // your input element object
  .parent()    // the span which encloses your input element
  .next('div') // the div which immediately follows your span
  .children()  // everything inside your div
  .first()     // the first element inside your div
)              // closes insertBefore()
```

Then since you also need to toggle the `<div>` container along with the error message, you'll need to use the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions and a couple jQuery DOM traversal methods...

```
highlight: function (element) {
    $(element).parent().next('div').show();
},
unhighlight: function (element) {
    $(element).parent().next('div').hide();
}
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/naa6w/**

Comment: thanks @sparky for elaborate explanation. Apologies for the shabby code and delayed response though.