# Customize jQuery Validation inserted HTML

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am having trouble editing the inserted HTML using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) (version 1.12.0 with jQuery 1.9.1). I would like to add a Font Awesome icon inside the created error element. It would be before the error message, meaning a nice exclamation mark is shown before the message.

**What I would like:**

```
<input type="text" id="email" />
<span for="email" class="invalid">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> This field is required.
</span>
```

**What it would look like:**

[image: Desired output]

**What I have so far:**

```
$(".validate-form").validate({
    errorClass: "invalid",
    errorElement: "span"
});
```

I can actually achieve this by just editing the default messages to include the HTML, but it is sort of a hacky way to do it. **This is what I am doing that is achieving the desired results:**

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: '<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + "This field is required."
});
```

I have also tried using the `errorPlacement` callback, but had no luck. Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Comment: did you try to change the image in the `fa-exclamation-circle" inside the css of the plugin?

Comment: I did not. Can you expand on what you mean? I don't believe the jQuery Validation plugin comes with any CSS, just JS.

Comment: could you give a link for this plugin?

Comment: Sure. I edited my question with a link. Or just go to http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [custom html inside errorElement of jquery Validate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19159305/custom-html-inside-errorelement-of-jquery-validate)

Comment: Thanks @Sparky. I had been looking all over for something like that SO question. So I need to make the changes in the `errorPlacement` callback, or in the `highlight`/`unhighlight` callbacks (or both)?

Comment: `errorPlacement` is for _placement_ of the message on the page.  `highlight/unhighlight` are for toggling the (classes) on the element.

Comment: So if you follow [my other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19168952/594235), you'll need to use both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your desired output:

```
<input type="text" id="email" />
<span for="email" class="invalid">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> This field is required.
</span>
```

First thing wrong is that your `input` is missing the `name` attribute.  The `name` attribute is mandatory for this plugin.  Also, AFAIK, you cannot use the `for` attribute with anything but a `label`.  The message itself will be inside a `label` container unless you change it with `errorElement: "span"`.

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<span class="invalid">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i><span>This field is required.</span>
</span>
```

Create your desired HTML markup and set it to `display: none`.  Use CSS to insert some space before the error message.

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<span class="invalid" style="display: none;">
    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
</span>
```

Then try something like this...

```
errorClass: 'invalid',  // default "error"
errorElement: 'span',   // default "label"
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element.next('span').children());
},
highlight: function (element) {
    $(element).next('span').show();
},
unhighlight: function (element) {
    $(element).next('span').hide();
}
```